# Jquery Full Calendar Questions - Color on group of events & multiple event sources

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I am looking at jquery full calendar 1.5 and have a couple questions.

How would multiple source look like?

```
jQuery $.ajax options

You can also specify any of the jQuery $.ajax options within the same object! This allows you to easily pass additional parameters to your feed script, as well as listen to ajax callbacks:

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        eventSources: [

            // your event source
            {
                url: '/myfeed.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    custom_param1: 'something',
                    custom_param2: 'somethingelse'
                }
                error: function() {
                    alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                },
                color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
                textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
            }

            // any other sources...

        ]

    });
```

from: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/

Would you just put a comma and then copy basically the first one?

My second question is. I am going to have one event source(since they all come from the same source) but I will have groups of events in there and each group needs a different color.

So I could have this

```
Item 1 - group 1 (color red)
Item 2 - group 1 (color red)
Item 3 - group 2  (color green)
Item 4 - group 3 (color black)
```

Now these colors are set by the user so I will never know what color group one will be. One user might set it red one might set it blue.

So I thinking that I need to send the color with each event. So Item 1 would have a color associated with it and Item 2 would have a color associated and etc.

How would do this? I am thinking I need to do something once I get the events back. I am just not sure what.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To handle multiple sources, you're right, just add more to the eventSources array:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    eventSources: [

        // your event source
        {
            url: '/myfeed.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                custom_param1: 'something',
                custom_param2: 'somethingelse'
            }
            error: function() {
                alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
            },
            color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
            textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
        },

        // your second event source
        {
            url: '/myfeed.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                custom_param3: 'somethingelseelse',
                custom_param4: 'somethingelseelseelse'
            }
            error: function() {
                alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
            },
            color: 'red',   // a non-ajax option
            textColor: 'white' // a non-ajax option
        }

        // any other sources...

    ]

});
```

As far as different colors for multiple groups, fullCalendar only allows one color per event source.  So you'll have to add one source to eventSource for each group you have.  And as far as letting the user customize their colors, using the example above, you can have something like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    eventSources: [

        // your event source
        {
            url: '/myfeed.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                custom_param1: 'something',
                custom_param2: 'somethingelse'
            }
            error: function() {
                alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
            },
            color: settings.customBackgroundColors(userId, groupX),   // a non-ajax option
            textColor: settings.customTextColors(userId, groupX) // a non-ajax option
        },

        // your second event source
        {
            url: '/myfeed.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                custom_param3: 'somethingelseelse',
                custom_param4: 'somethingelseelseelse'
            }
            error: function() {
                alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
            },
            color: settings.customBackgroundColors(userId, groupY),   // a non-ajax option
            textColor: settings.customTextColors(userId, groupY) // a non-ajax option
        }

        // any other sources...

    ]

});
```

---

**Edit**

If you want individual properties for each of your events from a json feed like a individual color do something like this.

```
public int id { get; set; }
public string title { get; set; }
public bool allDay { get; set; }
public string start { get; set; }
public string end { get; set; }
public string color { get; set; }
public string textColor { get; set; }
```

fill in the string with the color you want make a collection of what I have for each event and then send it back a a json result and each task should use whatever you set in the color property.

Comment: @Milimetric - For the color can't I somehow change the color before the cell is rendered? I been looking at "eventRender" callback but I am unsure how to force it change colors. I can't do what you suggested because I would have an unknown number of groups(it could be one group it could be 50). I would also try to send it all back in one request.

Comment: Um, you could examine what the HTML looks like after the calendar loads.  Then you could just use jQuery to select and style all you want.

Comment: @Milimetric - Ya thats the way I gone and done it but kinda sucks since I have to remove generated classes and stuff. Would be nice if you could get control of the color before render and change it but I guess that is not possible right now.

Comment: yeah, maybe they'll update it later.  You couldn't just hook into the generated classes and override the style?  like `$('.generated-class').css('background-color', 'purple')` or something?

Comment: @Milimetric - Would this add a inline style?

Comment: yes, it would make `<td class="something">` into `<td class="something" style="background-color: purple;">`.  (I know you know that but there's a 20 character minimum so I had to explain it :)

Comment: @ Milimetric - Actually it seems you can do this. It's so simple. I removed color from the sources. Then from the server I generate my json and for each event I set the color so color: black, color: red in each event and it works!

Comment: @ Milimetric  - now I just need to figure out how to dynamically change the text color.

Comment: @Milimetric - and they have a setting for it as well!

Comment: sweet, feel free to edit my answer with what you found.  Or edit your question.  Or post your own answer :)

Answer (score 3):

what i did was:

```
$color = '#000';

if($i == even){
  $color = '#fff';
}

{

"title": "your title",
"start": date('Y m d'),
"end": date('Y m d', strtotime("+1 day")),
"color": $color

}
```

and it works.... no need of complicated codes!!

Comment: you can also change the textColor with `textColor:#fff` too!

Answer (score 0):

I know you've had quite the conversation about this already but I figured I'd throw out a suggestion.

If you have a predefined set of colors that the user can choose from you could setup predefined CSS classes and then just use the `className` property of fullcalendar.

On my calendar I basically color events if they're either in the future or already past and the past events use this css.

```
.fc-event,
.fc-agenda .past .fc-event-time,
.past a {
    background-color: green;
    boarder-color: green;
    color: white;
 }
```

where `.past` refers to my `className`.

Then when I'm compiling my JSON in a jsp it looks like this.

```
{
    "title": "<%=e.getName()%>",
    "start": "<%=startString %>",
    "end": "<%=endString%>",
    "allDay": false
    <%if(e.isFinished()){%>,"className": "past"<%}%> 
}
```

I tried playing with the color options and whatnot but this method worked best for me.

Comment: I don't want to use inline javascript and since the user can have X number of groups of events and X colors I can't really define them unless the style sheet would also be dynamically made.

Answer (score 0):

What I do to set different colors is get from event object returned from the json generated by my source. In the events i put something like this:

```
 events: function(start, end, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: GlobalAjax.ajaxurl+'calendar/events',
        data: {
            // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
            start: Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000),
            end: Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000)
        },
        success: function(doc) {
            var events = [];
            $(doc).each(function() {
                events.push({
                    title: $(this).attr('title'),
                    start: $(this).attr('start'), // will be parsed
                    end: $(this).attr('end'), // will be parsed
                    color: $(this).attr('color') // will be parsed
                });
            });
            callback(events);
        }
    });
```

It works like charm

Comment: _What I do to set different colors is get from event object_ get what?