# How do I change the color of an eventSource in (jQuery) FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with the following [plugin](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) and would like to change the color of the eventSource but I can't quite figure out what to do.

So far I have the following code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
       eventSources: [
        'events/get_events'
    ]
```

The [documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_array/) discusses an option to do this but I can't get the syntax right.

Is anyone able to help?

Comment: I take it that you already tried CSS

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('#calender').fullCalendar({
        eventSources: [
    'events/get_events',
    color: 'yellow',
    textColor: 'black'
   ]
});
```

Comment: check:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601236/jquery-full-calendar-questions-color-on-group-of-events-multiple-event-sourc